# Not sure why this is not working

Tags: java, loops, average

This is a program i'm stuck on for school. Can't figure out why it won't give me a average and a greatest. The program runs 50 times like i want it to but does not add a value to moves and total.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomWalk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Random rand = new Random();

        int location;
        double average;
        int greatest=0;
        int moves = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int step;

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

            location = 4;
            step = rand.nextInt((2 - 1) + 1) + 1;


            while (location < 1 || location > 7) {
                moves ++;
                if (step == 2){
                    location ++;    
                } else {
                    location --;
                }
                if (moves > greatest) {
                    greatest = moves;
                    total += moves;
                }
            }
        }

        average = total / 50;

        System.out.println("The greatest number of steps: " + greatest);
        System.out.println("The average number of steps:  " + average);

     }

}
```

fixed the for loop but it still does not give me the average and the greatest.

as for the `while (location < 1 || location > 7)` it should run till the person stands on location 1 or location 7.

here is the problem i was given:

In the "random walk", a person is placed at the center of a seven meter long bridge. Each step moves a person 1 meter either forward or backward at random.
Create a randomwalk that determines how many steps the person will walk before taking a step off the bridge. Have the application average 50 trials, and display the average and the greatest number of steps.

thanks for helping...

if i change it to this: `import java.util.*;

public class RandomWalk2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Random rand = new Random();
    double average;
    int greatest=0;
    int moves;
    int total = 0;
    int step;

    step = rand.nextInt((2 - 1) + 1) + 1;

    int location; //location of man on bridge
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
       moves = 0;
       moves++;
       location = 4;
       total += moves;
       while(true)
       {
          if (step == 2) {
           location++;
          } else {
           location--;
          }

         if((location < 1) || (location > 7)) break;
       }

      if(moves > greatest) {
      greatest = moves;

      }


      }

    average = total / 50;

    System.out.println("The greatest number of steps: " + greatest);
    System.out.println("The average number of steps:  " + average);


    }

}
```

`
then it runs 50 times but the guy only moves 1 stop so my greatest and average always shows as 1.

Comment: Now would be a great time to learn to use a debugger. Alternatively, use pen and paper.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't loop 50 times, because your `for` loop condition is incorrect.  The `for` loop continues iterating if the condition is `true`, not `false`.  Change your condition from

```
for (int i = 0; i == 50; i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
```

Then it will run until `i < 50` is `false` (50 times).

Comment: i fixed that problem but can you tell me why the average and the greatest still do not show up when i run it??

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the basics of a for loop.

> for (initialization; termination;
>        increment) {
>       statement(s)
>   }

When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:

> The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed
>   once, as the loop begins. When the termination expression evaluates to
>   false, the loop terminates. The increment expression is invoked after
>   each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this
>   expression to increment or decrement a value.

The following link should be helpful:

[Java for loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: I will keep that in mind for future reference.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the loop.. my teacher at school isn't very good at java... since she doesn't even know it..

Answer (score 0):

```
location = 4;
step = rand.nextInt((2 - 1) + 1) + 1;
while (location < 1 || location > 7) {
    ..
}
```

When will location be less than 1 or greater than 7?

Also the for loop as mentioned by rgettman

Comment: The bridge is 7 meters long and the guy is in the middle.. numbering 1-7 the middle would be 4. So i want the loop to run while he is not on 1 or 7.

Comment: I meant to direct you to the problem. You initialize location to 4, then check when it is not 1 or 7. Unless your object is modified concurently your while loop wont execute