# Trouble on getting my for loop to work

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am attempting to do a coin toss simulator but no matter what I do this for loop gets skipped and returns 0 heads and 0 tails. The randNumgenerator is defined before but I don't think it has anything to do with my issue.

Note: "not working" never shows up while I am running it, so I'm assuming it's a problem with the loop itself and not what's inside of the loop. I've also set the loop exit condition to 4 even though when this program is finished it will execute any amount of coin tosses the user wants.

here is my section of code. Can anyone tell me why I always get 0 heads and 0 tails?

```
final int sidesOfCoin = 2;
int flipsDone = 0;
int heads = 0;
int tails = 0;
int randomCoinValue;

for (heads = 0 ; flipsDone == 4; flipsDone++){
    randomCoinValue = randNumGenerator.nextInt(sidesOfCoin);
    if(randomCoinValue == 0){
        heads++;
    }
    else if(randomCoinValue == 1){
        tails++;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("not working");
    }
}

System.out.println(heads + " heads and " + tails + " tails means " + (((double)heads * 100)/flipsDone) + "% tosses were heads");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not sure why this is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788190/not-sure-why-this-is-not-working)

Comment: `flipsDone == 4`. With which value did you initialize `flipsDone`? Is this condition true when starting the first iteration?

Comment: flipsDone is initialized to 0. But Petar pointed out what I did wrong. Thank you though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `flipsDone <= 4`? Otherwise you are exiting the loop immediately.

Comment: wow. I clearly wasn't understanding how the for loop works. Thank you.